# Calculated column to sum all matching values based on three criteria

Tags: excel, dax

Given the following table:

| Hole | VertFrom | VertTo | Len | Center |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20.97 | 22.18 | 1.21 | 21.575 |
| A | 22.18 | 22.57 | 0.39 | 22.375 |
| A | 22.57 | 24.09 | 1.52 | 23.33 |
| A | 24.09 | 25.57 | 1.48 | 24.83 |
| B | 25.57 | 27.08 | 1.51 | 26.325 |
| B | 27.08 | 28.39 | 1.31 | 27.735 |
| B | 28.39 | 29.51 | 1.12 | 28.95 |

I need to create a calculated column as follows:

1. given var vINT = X
2. where VertFrom >= Center -vINT/2 AND VertTo <= Center + vINT/2
3. add all Len values for the current hole

Example result (vINT = 2):

| Hole | VertFrom | VertTo | Len | Center | vINT = 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20.97 | 22.18 | 1.21 | 21.575 | 1.6 |
| A | 22.18 | 22.57 | 0.39 | 22.375 | 0.39 |
| A | 22.57 | 24.09 | 1.52 | 23.33 | 1.52 |
| A | 24.09 | 25.57 | 1.48 | 24.83 | 1.48 |
| B | 25.57 | 27.08 | 1.51 | 26.325 | 1.51 |
| B | 27.08 | 28.39 | 1.31 | 27.735 | 1.31 |
| B | 28.39 | 29.51 | 1.12 | 28.95 | 1.12 |

Row 1 is where you should see that there are two matches for the filter criteria and the result is "1.6" = "1.21 + 0.39"

The Excel array formula that generates the accurate result is here:

=SUM($D$2:$D$8*($A$2:$A$8=$A2)*($B$2:$B$8>=$E2-F$1/2)*($C$2:$C$8<=$E2+F$1/2))

Where

- A:A = Hole
- B:B = VertFrom
- C:C = VertTo
- D:D = Len
- E:E = Center
- F1 = 2

I have tried so many things to get this working and am at my wits' end. My most recent attempt is below:

```
=
var vINT = 2
var vHOLE = TEST[Hole]
var vCENTER = TEST[Center]
var vVERTTO = TEST[VertTo]
var vVERTFROM = TEST[VertFrom]
var TESTONE = FILTER(TEST,TEST[VertFrom] >= TEST[Center]-vINT/2 && TEST[VertTo]<=TEST[Center] + vINT/2)
var vTEST = SELECTCOLUMNS(TEST, "HOLE", TEST[Hole], "LENGTH", TEST[Len])

RETURN

SUMX(CALCULATETABLE(TEST,TEST[Hole]=vHOLE,TEST[VertFrom]>=vCENTER-vINT/2,TEST[VertTo]<=vVERTTO+vINT/2),[Len])
```

Thanks to any and all who can assist.

Answer (score 0):

Try with SELECTEDVALUE (based on with value you want comparing on THIS/Current row):

```
xVert 2 = 
var vINT = 2
return
CALCULATE( SUM('Sheet1 (2)'[Len]), FILTER(ALL('Sheet1 (2)'), 
SELECTEDVALUE('Sheet1 (2)'[Hole]) = 'Sheet1 (2)'[Hole] &&
SELECTEDVALUE( 'Sheet1 (2)'[VertFrom]) >= ('Sheet1 (2)'[Center] -vINT/2) && 
SELECTEDVALUE('Sheet1 (2)'[VertTo]) <= ('Sheet1 (2)'[Center] + vINT/2) ))
```

[image]

Comment: SELECTEDVALUE isn't available in DAX for Excel. Formatting in comments doesn't work for me to show how I've used your feedback. It seems I'll have to post an answer to show what I've done.

Answer (score 0):

Based on feedback from @msta42a, I'm one step closer.

```
=
var vINT = 2
var vHOLE = TEST[Hole]
var vCENTER = TEST[Center]
var vVERTTO = TEST[VertTo]
var vVERTFROM = TEST[VertFrom]

RETURN

CALCULATE(
    SUM([Len]), 
        FILTER(
            TEST,
            vHOLE = TEST[Hole] && vVERTFROM >= TEST[Center] -vINT/2 && vVERTTO <= TEST[Center] + vINT/2)

)
```

SELECTEDVALUE isn't available in DAX for Excel but using the variables I can apply the row context to the now-improved filter context suggested by @msta42a; however, there is still an issue.

For all vINT values OTHER than 2, the results are good. For vINT = 2, however, it's not.

DAX RESULTS

- vINT = 2
- Row 1 result is 1.21
- Row 2 result is 1.6

ARRAY FORMULA RESULTS

- vINT = 2
- Row 1 result is 1.6
- Row 2 result is 0.39

This is now an even worse problem because it appears to me that this should work.

I have tried with and without the ALL(TABLE) statement - no change - and would prefer to avoid ALL statements as this table has 600,000 rows.

Comment: Upon more testing, the results for other vINT values are also wrong. I'm totally stumped.